# MustacheJS - access value by property as index

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

Scope :

```
let bases = [{id: "51667c34ed4dd", name: "CAYENNE", sort: 1}, {id: "516682b6a160e", name: "FORT DE FRANCE", sort: 2}, {id: "516682c230fbb", name: "POINT A PITRE", sort: 3}];
let filters = {bases: {51667c34ed4dd: true, 516682b6a160e: false, 516682c230fbb: true}, aircrafts: {}};
let set = {bases, filters};
```

Template :

```
{{#bases}}
    <input type="checkbox" class="base_checkbox" value="1" id="{{id}}" name="{{name}}" {{(if checked)}}checked="checked"{{/(if checked)}}>
{{/bases}}
```

Usage :

```
Mustache.render(template, set);
```

In `{{#bases}}` loop, how can i access another external object value with current scope property as key ?

like : {{filters.bases **{{id}}** }} where {{id}} is the property of current object in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with :

```
bases.forEach(b => {
    b.checked = () => {
        return filters["bases"][b.id];
    }
});
```

Mustache use the function returned value as variable.